# Calculating bottom quartile performers with Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Brand new to Pandas (Python) here and am cutting my teeth with some lightweight analytics, but am having some difficulty getting started.

I have a spreadsheet with the following data in it:

```
Fruit,HarvestCount,HarvestDate
Apple,100,08/03/2022
Banana,2500,04/15/2022
Apple,4000,10/11/2022
Pineapple,5,02/07/2022
Pear,250,06/09/2022
Banana,1000,08/11/2022
Orange,20,07/23/2022
Orange,140,11/29/2022
Strawberry,600,12/11/2022
Apple,5000,04/01/2022
Pear,10,07/07/2022
Banana,50,10/19/2022
```

I am reading this Excel into a dataframe like so:

```
data = pd.read_excel('fruit-harvests.xlsx', sheet_name='Harvests')
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now what I am trying to do is:

- collapse the dataframe by "Fruit" name and sum each fruit's Harvest Count; then
- figure out the who the bottom 25% quartile performers were (that is, the bottom 25% fruits with the lowest summed harvest count)

Hence if I did this manually, the collapse + sum would look like:

```
Apple,9100
Banana,3550
Pineapple,5
Pear,260
Orange,160
Strawberry,600
```

Sorted by `HarvestCount` descending it looks like:

```
Apple,9100
Banana,3550
Strawberry,600
Pear,260
Orange,160
Pineapple,5
```

Since after the collapse we see there are six (6) distinct fruits, the bottom quartile would be the worst-performing 1.5 fruits, or rounded up, the worst 2 fruits:

```
Orange,160
Pineapple,5
```

So from the time I read my Excel into a dataframe, I have to:

1. Sum/aggregate/collapse
2. Sort by HarvestCount descending (or ascending whichever is easier for the next step)
3. And finally create a new dataframe of the worst-performing 25% of fruits (rows)

Can anyone point me in the right direction here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

Grouping and aggregate the count:

```
df_temp = df_temp.groupby('Fruit', as_index =False).agg(count = ('HarvestCount', 'sum')
```

Sorting:

```
df_temp = df_temp.sort_values('count', ascending = False, ignore_index = True)
```

25% worst:

```
import math

percent = math.ceil((25/100) * len(df_temp))
df = df_temp(tail(percent))
```